# Passing the ID of the Dynamic Span ID to load a file with jquery

Tags: javascript

I have the Span Tag with the id attribute having different value inside a loop

like this:

```
<span class="articlehelp" id="#faqID#"></span>
```

I have the following jquery declared on dom ready

```
$('.articlehelp').load('getvoting.cfm?id=' + $('.articlehelp').prop('id'));
```

But it is loading everytime 1 rather than different id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that the selector for `.acticlehelp` selects all matching elements, but caling functions on this always takes the first matched element from the collection.

You need to loop over all `.articlehelp` to achive what you want.

I am not an expert in jquery but something like this may do:

```
$('.articlehelp').each(function (i, element) {
  $(element).load('getvoting.cfm?id=' + $(element).prop('id'));
});
```

Comment: Yes That's What i was looking for, Cheers mate! Thanks, need one correction, just put closing parenthesis at the end